# SQL Server 2008 query to select correct record based on multiple rules

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like this in SQL Server 2008:

| Company_Refno | CompanyID | IsActive | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | Y | 2/10/2000 | 2/11/2000 |
| 100 | 2 | Y | 2/10/2000 | NULL |
| 100 | 3 | N | 3/10/2000 | 2/11/2000 |
| 100 | 4 | N | 3/10/2000 | 2/11/2000 |
| 101 | 5 | Y | 5/5/1998 | 6/7/2008 |
| 101 | 6 | Y | 2/2/1998 | 6/7/2008 |
| 102 | 7 | Y | 11/11/2007 | 12/12/2010 |
| 102 | 7 | Y | 11/11/2007 | 12/12/2010 |

My requirement is that:

a) For a given Company_Refno, take at least 1 active ID (i.e. IsActive = Y), then take that 
b) If a company has more than 1 active ID, but only 1 open record (i.e. end date is null), take that 
c) If company has multiple active records, with multiple closed end dates, then take earliest end date record 
d) If End dates are same then take earliest start date 
e) If start dates are the same, take top 1

So in this sample, for Company_Refno 100, I would have ID 2 selected (since it is active & end date is NULL), 
RefNo 101, ID 6 will be selected (active, earliest start date), 
 RefNo 102, ID 7 (top 1 ) will be selected (since both start and end dates are same)

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this using SQL Query?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to solve it using row_number() function

```
select * from 
(
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY COMPANY_REFNO ORDER BY 
    case when isnull(iSaCTIVE,'y') = 'Y' then 1 when IsActive !='n' then 2 end asc,     
      isnull(EndDate,'31-dec-9999') desc, StartDate asc)       
    AS RANK_NO FROM
MyTable
) AA
where rank_no = 1
```

However, I welcome other solutions from people!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to order the records and get the top 1:

```
select top 1 Company_Refno, CompanyID, IsActive, StartDate, EndDate
from mytable
where Company_Refno = 100 -- replace that with a parameter
and IsActive = 'Y' -- condition a)
order by
    case when EndDate is null then 0 else 1 end, -- condition b)
    EndDate, -- condition c)
    StartDate -- condition d)
```

Comment: I want the results for all valid ID record(s), for every Company_Refno, and not just one Company_RefNo or top 1 record.

Comment: Ok, in this case I don't think I'll come up with anything better than your solution. I started going the same direction. Well done.

Comment: Hi, there is a new condition to this old requirement!! In point e) in my question, i.e. if startDates are same, then we should take max of Company_RefNo (e.g. if company refnos are 100_10, 101_10, 103_10, then 103_10 record must be selected if both startdates and enddates are same for all 3 above records).. Any answer? Thanks!